# Maximum size of cards inside a canvas

Tags: html, math, canvas

I am now working with a Web Application, which needs to draw some cards on a fixed rectangle canvas.  Below is the criteria:

1. The canvas size is fixed with width "w" and height "h" when the Web Application starts.
2. There are "n" no. of cards which won't be changed after started.
3. All cards must in the same size, which has a fixed ratio with width "cw" and height "ch", the cards are able to re-size within the canvas.

I would like to calculate the maximum width and height of each card in such cases.  Can anybody help?

Comment: The maximum size? Do you mean the maximum area?

Comment: Yes, I would like to find maximum width and height allowed of each card

Answer (score 1):

Your question is lacking a lot of information. please read the comments in the code. I hope my answer may help you.

```js
// initiate the canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 300,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = 300,
  cy = ch / 2;

// number of cards
let n = 12;
// the horizontal and vertical ratio 
let ratio = {x:.2,y:.3}
// the width and the height of a card
let w = cw*ratio.x;
let h = ch*ratio.y;
// a counter
let i = 0;
//a double for loop to draw the cards
for(let y = 0; y<ch; y+=h){
for(let x = 0; x<cw; x+=w){
  if(i < n)
  {drawCard(x,y);
  i++}
}
}

function drawCard(x,y){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution myself.

This performance may not is the optimal one, but the solution gives me the new card width, new card height, cards per rows and cards per column.  So that the cards can almost cover the canvas.

```js
function crwh(col, row, n, cw, ch, w, h, exactN) {
  // Methods
  this.fn_init = function(col, row) {
   this.col = col;
   this.row = row;
   
   if (this.col > 0 && this.row > 0) {
    // Calculate new card width & card height base on col
    this.cw_new = (this.w / this.col);
    this.ch_new = (this.cw_new / this.cw * this.ch);
     
    if (this.fn_valid() == false) {
     // Calculate new card height & card width base on row
     this.ch_new = (this.h / this.row);
     this.cw_new = (this.ch_new / this.ch * cw);
    }
   }
  }
  
  this.fn_area = function() {
   // Get the size the rectangle
   return this.cw_new * this.ch_new;
  }
  
  this.fn_valid = function() {
   var valid = true;
   
   // True if col * row must equal to no. of cards, False allow col * row greater than no. of cards
   valid = valid && ((this.exactN == true && (this.col * this.row) == this.n) || (this.exactN == false && (this.col * this.row) >= this.n));
   // col * card width (new) must be shorter than canvas width
   
   valid = valid && ((this.col * this.cw_new) <= this.w);
   
   // row * card height (new) must be shorter than canvas height
   valid = valid && ((this.row * this.ch_new) <= this.h);
   
   return valid;
  }
  
  // Properties
  this.n = n;
  this.cw = cw;
  this.ch = ch;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.exactN = exactN;

  this.col = 0;
  this.row = 0;
  
  this.cw_new = 0;
  this.ch_new = 0;
  
  this.fn_init(col, row);
 }

 function fn_getCardDimensions(n, cw, ch, w, h, exactN) {
  var crwh_max = new crwh(0, 0);
  
  // Loop thru 1 to n for col & row to see which combination allow a maximum card size
  for (var col = 1; col <= n; col++) {
   for (var row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
    if ((col * row) >= n) {
     var crwh_cur = new crwh(col, row, n, cw, ch, w, h, exactN);
     
     if (crwh_cur.fn_valid()) {
      
      if (crwh_cur.fn_area() > crwh_max.fn_area()) {
       crwh_max = crwh_cur;
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

  return [crwh_max.col, crwh_max.row, crwh_max.cw_new, crwh_max.ch_new];
 }
 
 var n = 80;    // No. of Cards
 var cw = 344;   // Card Width (orig)
 var ch = 512;   // Card Height (orig)
 var w = 0;    // Canvas Width
 var h = 0;    // Canvas Height
 var exactN = true;  // True if col * row must equal to no. of cards
 
 
 function fn_drawCards() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;
  
  [col, row, cw_new, ch_new] = fn_getCardDimensions(n, cw, ch, w, h, exactN);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < row; j++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeRect(i * cw_new, j * ch_new, cw_new, ch_new);
   }
  }  
 }
  
  fn_drawCards();
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid #00FF00;
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```